# Replacing Positional arguments - calling a function with or without tuple arguments

Tags: python, arguments, tuples

```
def withPositionalArgs(*args):
    print args, type(args)

def withTupleAsArgument(tupleArg):
    print tupleArg, type(tupleArg)

a=1
b=2
c=[10,20]

print withPositionalArgs(a,b,c)
print withTupleAsArgument(tuple([a,b,c]))
```

When I run this code:

```
(1, 2, [10, 20]) <type 'tuple'>
None
(1, 2, [10, 20]) <type 'tuple'>
None
```

Doubts:

As positional arguments are passed as a tuple, is there techcnially any difference between these 2 function calls? If I can already make a tuple at the time I'm calling, is there a need to use Positional arguments ? Things can work without them too, ain't it ? Or is there something that I have not understood or ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask yourself how your function will be used. Is it more natural to think of the arguments as an unrelated set of values, in which case positional arguments make more sense. Or do the values form a related group, in which case a tuple makes more sense.

You also need to consider how your function may be used. Suppose you have a function
that returns a tuple of values:

```
def foo():
    return 1,2,3
```

and you want to write a function `bar` whose arguments are those values returned by `foo`. Your two choices are

```
# Take a sequence of values and store them in a tuple called args
def bar1(*args):
    print args[0]

# Take a tuple of values and store it in t
def bar2(t):
    print t[0]
```

Here are some ways you might call each of the two functions, using the return value of `foo` directly as your argument(s):

```
>>> bar1(foo())  # Receives a single tuple-valued argument
(1, 2, 3)
>>> bar1(*foo()) # Receives 3 integer arguments
1
>>> bar2(foo())  # Receives a single tuple-valued argument
1
>>> bar2(*foo()) # Receives 3 arguments, but only expected 1!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar2() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

So the choice between `bar1` and `bar2` really depends on how you expect it to be used.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no difference between the two. In the first one your args end up in a tuple, the the second one you are sending a tuple.

Comment: Deos that mean that If I can already make a tuple at the time I'm calling, there is no need to use Positional arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

The big difference is that  the positional arguments "*args" way allow one to call, at runtime, a function for which he does nt know the number of arguments, and still have the same function work as a "plain" function for other calls.

It is most often (but not solelly) used when one sends  a function as parameter to another piece of code, or, write a function wrapper that will receive "N" arguments and pass those "N" arguments to the original funciton, without caring about them.

It is an essential part of what makes writting dynamic code in Python so great.

For example:

```
def MySum(a,b):
    return a + b

def logger(func):
   def wrapper(*args):
       print args
       return func(*args)
   return wrapper

MySum = logger(MySum)
```

This code snippet creates a decorator to print out the arguemtns passed to a function, still can work with any function called with positional arguments only.(Adding the keyword parameters would make it work for any callable at all).

Still any code which used the original version of `MySun`can continue to do so unchanged.
If one where using a normal tuple to pass parameters to the decorator, the calling code would have to be modified accordingly.